# Domain GPO removes USB-C docks driver under Win10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, group-policy

First a little background.

I have a Dell Precision 7510 laptop @ work, connected to a Dell WD15 connected via USB-C.

- Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
- Version  10.0.15063 Build 15063
- System Type  x64-based PC

My problem is that when connected to the dock, everything working, all of a sudden, the dock is removed, and drivers need to be manually installed, to get it working again.

I have been looking into the problem, and believe rooted cause to be my companies group policies, pushed via the domain, but I have thus fare not been able to get them to fix it, and I am therefore exploring if other options are available.

I have been investigating the event log when the dock is thrown offline, and found that it all starts with an GPO update:
[image]

Then right after, the device is deleted:
[image]

The the device throws an error:
[image]

Then an info that the device requires further installation:
[image]

Then an info that driver install failed with code 0xE0000248:
[image]

To my knowledge, this code 0xE0000248 reads:

> The installation of this device is forbidden by system policy.

This is what lead me to believe that GPO were to blame, and after some digging, I found:
[image]

and when examining the "PCI to PCI Bridge" properties, I found this list of compatibles ID's for the hardware:

[image]

Based on the fact that "PCI\CC_0C0A" are mentioned in both, I believe the removal are triggered by the GPO. If anyone has reason to disagree with my conclusion, kindly say so, with explanation why.

At long last, my question. I am interested in knowing from where the list of compatible ID's comes?

Case #1:
When windows detects a new device, the device informs this list to windows, which then tries to locate an appropriate driver based on the list.

Case #2:
The list somehow comes from windows and/or driver inf files, and windows then tries to locate an appropriate driver based on the list.

Case #3:
Something completely different?

If #2 is what happens, is there then a way for me to remove "PCI\CC_0C0A" from the list of compatible ID's, thereby hopefully preventing the GPO from removing the dock?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards
Henrik V. Nielsen

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much an answer, as my current workaround.

Therefore my original question, how to prevent the USB-C dock from registering "PCI\CC_0C0A" as a compatible device ID, still remains. If possible?

**Update**
The disconnect happened a lot of time during a normal work day, and required me to manually reinstall 4 drivers to get it up and running again.

I have successfully created a script to ease the problem.

The script does the following:

- Elevates itself to administrator (based on a script found in a post on this site)
- Enables policy "Turn off background refresh of GPO", by adding "DisableBkGndGroupPolicy" in registry
- Delete the offending company GPO from registry
- Elevate the script to TrustedInstaller (3 party program called PowerRun)
- Delete all traces of old USB dock drivers from registry (found that they sometimes generated problems)
- This leaves a disconnect and reconnect of the USB-C to be performed by me

In the morning, the GPO always find a way to update (does not happen when rebooting during the day, weird), but above usually dropping the need to re-install to that one time. Also the only action required by me is to disconnect and reconnect the USB-C once the script has been executed.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: I disagree; it is a workaround, and a pretty clearly described one.  A workaround is a form of an answer.  The only thing that would make this even more answer-y would be if the script was included.

Comment: Is there any reason you do not get with the domain admins to help adjust domain policies to the machine with the problem? There is a lot of flexibility they should have to ensure those specific settings do not apply to the machines it should not be run on. The GPOs are supposed to help simplify while allowing scale, not cause some problem and because it's domain GPO, it is something we cannot change or have to figure out a workaround to resolve; adjust the GPOs accordingly for the root cause solution. Go ahead and tell your admin the specific GPOs that need segregated to omit for the machine.

Comment: Hi Vomit IT.

How did you dig up this old thing ;)

Unfortunately, in the process of learning by doing, previous communications with IT departments has thought me, that when a company reaches a certain size, and hence the IT does the same, they (IT) tend to only focus on procedures/safety, and totally forgetting (start to dont care) about the usability for the end user.

Comment: When said sizer has been reached, I am sorry to say that I have only experienced "no, that can't be done" and the likes answers. Instead I would love to se them go into a dialogue with me as the end user, something like "no, that not possible under the current ruleset, but could such and such solve you problem".

Not to start a discussion ore anything, simply stating what history has taught me.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think maybe the community bot moved it up somehow. That is funny, I did not realize it was old either I don't think. That is funny though, "*How did I dig up this old thing*".... Lol, that's how it goes around here SU style, keep it moving.... Choo Choo!! Check Event Viewer | Applications and Services | Group Policy, operational logs, then filter event ids `5313` and `5312` both machine and user level GPO names applied including those "denied access" with GPO security filtering. Ask them to show you print out of one of those, then next day, another, then another... and so on!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing:  You aren't wrestling with a technical problem.  It looks like one, it acts like one, and you've found a technical workaround, but fundamentally you have a people problem.

In this case, the people that fundamentally control the computer that you are using (you have an admin account, but as you have shared, that does not give you enough control to solve this problem) seem to have created a policy (GPO) that prevents you from making full use of this hardware.

While you can continue to work around this technically, you are putting yourself at some risk by intentionally working around a policy that they have presumably at least limited justification for from a security perspective.  Hopefully your employer isn't a jerk about things like that, but some are, and it could have an impact on your job.  I suspect it is also inconvenient.

Fortunately, I think there is a real opportunity to address this by compromise.  First, here is an article that may be driving the admins in this case: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/blocking-the-sbp-2-driver-and-thunderbolt-controllers-to-reduce-1394-dma-and-thunderbolt-dma-threats-to-bitlocker-bf0ef10b-f563-5cfc-9740-8340b1d86a0c].  The "Thunderbolt Mitigation" section is the most relevant, as that is where the device ID comes from.

Second, prepare your justification.  Presumably you are adding this device to the computer for some reason.  Probably it helps you work, even if that is by letting you use an external monitor, keyboard or mouse that is more convenient for you / makes you more comfortable.  To the extent you can explain how this benefits the organization, you are better prepared to push your organization (be it your supervisor or the IT team) to exert any effort.

In the first sentence of the relevant section of the article is the first opportunity for compromise.  If your system is newer (there is a link that presumably goes into more detail) and on a newer version of Windows 10 (very likely?), the device removal isn't needed, and you can probably be excepted from the policy with no compromise in security.  Alternatively, you can argue that it makes sense to upgrade your computer early so that you can make use of this hardware to make you more efficient.

Alternatively, if you read the rest of the article, other mitigations might be to disable standby mode for the computer, and to disable TPM-only authentication for Bitlocker (which would mean that you might need to enter a password to start the computer; you can judge whether that tradeoff is worth it for you).

Another option would be to work out with the team how / whether  the sentence "Note that Thunderbolt 3 on the new USB Type-C connector includes new security features which can be configured to protect against this type of attack without disabling the port." offers any opportunities for mitigation (e.g. by switching to a newer or different device.).

Best of luck navigating your organization; hopefully you can make friends with some of the people in charge of making it possible for you and your team to actually get work done.  That will serve everyone well going forward.

Comment: Interesting article. Wish I would have found that back in 17/18 when I were having the issue.

Comment: Interesting article. Wish I would have found that back in 17/18 when I were having the issue. Seeing we were talking about a company supplied USB-C docking station for power/screens/peripherals/networking, I do find it kind of important.

Agreed. It is a workaround, and naturally, as such I were also potentially meddling with IT security. However, seeing that all new policies were pushed at least once a day, I do see this as a minor problem.

Comment: As interesting as I found the article you linked, I do not believe it should be necessary for a end user to even know about such articles to be able to talt to IT. I do believe it is IT responsibility to know of such, and of course implement safe guards against it, but also like as important, to do so in a way that doesn't render the end user equipment un usable.  Especially when this equipment has been delivered by themselves in the first place.